# UICollectionView centered pagination for a cell smaller than CollectionView's width

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, uikit

I am trying to have my cells around 0.85% the screen width so that the next and previous cells would be partially shown to tell the user that there are more cells.

I tried using many of the solutions on here along with `collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true` but the visible cell is never centered.

I expect the main cell that is shown to be centered regardless of whether there are more cells to its left/right or not.

This is the wrong behavior and my code. Thanks for any help.

Video:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MGdc.jpg

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // View preparation
    view.addSubview(mainTabBarView)
    mainTabBarView.configure()

    // Collection view
    mainTabBarView.collectionView.dataSource = self
    mainTabBarView.collectionView.delegate = self
  }
```

```
extension MainTabBarController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
  func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }
  
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
  }
  
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Cells.previewCell, for: indexPath) as! PreviewCell
    cell.configure()
    return cell
  }
}

extension MainTabBarController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width*0.85, height: collectionView.frame.size.height)
  }
}

extension MainTabBarController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 15
  }
  
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 15
  }
}
```

```
class MainTabBarView {
  // MARK:- Main configuration
  func configure() {
    ...
    setupCollectionView()
    ...
  }

  private func setupCollectionView() {
    let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: Int(screenWidth * 0.85), height: 68)
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 15
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 15
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(), collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = Colors.Primary.clear
    collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionView.register(PreviewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: Cells.previewCell)
    collectionView.allowsSelection = false
    collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20)
    collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a completed solution to the problem per se, but I see a couple of approaches which may help.

1. implement your own custom collection view layout so that you have full control on the cells layout and attributes, and you can make a logic in order to make the cell centered.
2. you make the collecview width 85% of the view controller width, and marking his clipToBounds as false, and finally setting the cell width to be like the collection view width. I did not test it but it could show the le left and right cell in the dequeue overflowing the boundaries of the collection view, as clipToBounds of the collection view is set to false. If you need to have a spacing between the cells, you could then actually wrap the visual content oer each cell in a view which has a certain margin from leading and trailing, and the result might be the same